# Access file on my external hard drive when I have no OS

Tags: windows, hard-drive, troubleshooting

I have no operating system on my computer. But I do have the Windows 7 installation file on my external harddrive, is it possible to load that iso file to run the windows 7 installation from my external harddrive?

Comment: So how did you get a web browser? ;) No really, what system do you have available now? You can for example try http://kmwoley.com/blog/?p=345

Comment: @Thomas:  Maybe Mach is really Commander Data using a pseudonym.  ;-D

Answer (score 1):

You could make the exteral drive bootable (I have a bootable USB stick created from searching here on SF).

Alternately, you could set up another pc as a PXE boot server and boot from the ISO over a network.

But it will likely save you hours (if not days) of fiddling to just burn the ISO to a DVD and install from that. Not as sexy, but it has Occam's Razor going for it.